# i'm able to select the database but it showing an error as mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Tags: php, database, mysqli

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    $link=@mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")or die(mysqli_error());
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysqli_error());
    }

    $db = mysqli_select_db($link,"name_of_db");
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }

    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        **return mysqli_real_escape_string ('mysqli $link','string $str');**
    }
?>
```

i'm able to connect to the server and database,but i'm getting an error at `return mysqli_real_escape_string ('mysqli $link','string $str');`

and it showing it as mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,i've gone through many answers but i'm not able to solve it,what i'm doing wrong while passing the parameters?

Comment: $link is not available inside the function, youd have to pass it in like you do with $str. But you should use prepared/parameterized queries to protect against sql injection hacks. If you do you dont have to use the escape string function.

Comment: i've executed after declaring $link as global variable inside the function but it won't solve the problem

Comment: Just remove it, when prepared/parameterized queries were introduced 10 years ago they rendered the mysql(i) escape string functions unecessary

Comment: That's because you're using single quotes. Variable interpolation in PHP only happens when you are using it in double quotes, i.e. `"mysql $link"` and not `'mysql $link'`. However, is there a reason why you are using manual string escape and concatenation instead of prepared statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as ur writing like `'$link'`, it acts as a string, and because it is in function , `$link` cannot be accessed like local variable, so u'll have to use `$GLOBALS['link']`.

so, replace the line with :-

```
return mysqli_real_escape_string ($GLOBALS['link'],$str);
```

hope it helps.. 
edited it. sorry i was only focusing on your question abt $link..

Comment: because str is a local variable and as it is declared as a string it should be in 'quotes' .   and thanks for the upvote.

Comment: dude i need one more help from u

Comment: what do you mean by , it will store $str, not what it contains?

Comment: ok, i got that now. you are saying in respective of string and all, but i thought u were saying abt the access of str in that function . yes it will echo the variable.

Comment: @Poorveshvyas Ok, I have removed my comments. That's better now.